# Trying to add ASP.NET controls to a tabbed jQuery module

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a page in my ASP.NET & C# website and i want it to have 3 different ASP.NET Repeaters, in the same page, and show each one in a different tab.

I got this snippet for tabbed content:
[Tabulous.js](http://git.aaronlumsden.com/tabulous.js/)

I implemented it in my page and it works well.

Now i tried to add a repeater inside it and it shows nothing, when i took the repeater out of the div of this module it was seen...

Later i tried adding a regular ASP.NET Button and it shows it but about half of it is unclickable.....

Here is my code:

```
    <div>

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1" title="">My Requests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2" title="">Idan Gay</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3" title="">Idan Koks</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs_container">
            <div id="tabs-1">
                Content for tab 1
            </div>

            <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>
                    Content for tab 2
                </p>

            </div>

            <div id="tabs-3">
                Content for tab 3
            </div>

        </div>
        <!--End tabs container-->

    </div>
    <!--End tabs-->

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Tabs/tabulous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Tabs/js.js"></script>
```

Like i said with only text it works fine, when i try to add some controls, that's where the problems are starting...

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason why you're using `Tabulous.js` over jQuery's tabs?  https://jqueryui.com/tabs/